# How go install finds out when to rebuild?

Tags: go, drone.io

I'm trying to use `go install` inside a drone build with caching(whole $GOPATH, see http://readme.drone.io/usage/caching/) and it works but `go install` rebuilds all packages doesn't matter what I do with the cache(I checked and cache store/restore seems to work correct - all .a files inside pkg are present)

How does `go install` find out what to rebuild?

edit: sigh... it must be caused by timestamps change, for some reason drone does not preserve them(access/modify/change change)

edit2: I found out I could use drone volumes for the same purpose, I did so and file access times as well as structure/contents are perfectly the same across builds - still `go install` ignores everything and rebuilds... What's the trick?